# Having some issues with my java program

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to do my java assignment. I am just struggling with some of the issues. I could not make the program calculates and outputs the information needed. When I try to run the program, and input the social security number, I get an error and a message saying

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
>     at Salaries.inputData(Salaries.java:34)     at
>   Salaries.main(Salaries.java:18)

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Here is a description of the program I am suppose to do.

> Write a program that reads Social Security numbers and salaries from the keyboard (Test this by only reading 3 or 4 to start). After the data is read in, the program should add a 2% raise to everyone’s salary. After you give the raise, print out 3 nicely formatted columns of information (Social, salary before raise, salary after raise). You will need a 3rd array holding the new salaries. A separate method should be used for the input, raise, and output.

This is the code I got so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class Salaries {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    int[] ssNumbers = new int [10];
    double[] salaries = new double [10];
    int c;
    int rais;

    c = inputData (ssNumbers, salaries);
    raise (salaries, c, ssNumbers);
    output (ssNumbers, salaries, nSalary);
}

public static int inputData (int[]ssn, double[]sals){
    int c = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    int ssNum;

    System.out.print("Enter social security number");
    ssNum = input.nextInt();

    while (ssNum != -1) //using while loop.
    {
        ssn[c] =  ssNum;

        System.out.print("Enter salary");
        sals[c] = input.nextDouble();
        c++;

        System.out.print("Please input next security numbers or -1 to quit");
        ssn[c] = input.nextInt(); 
    }
        return c;

}
public static void raise ( double[] salaries, int c, int[] ssNumbers)
{
    double salar;
    double rais = 0.02;

    for (int count = 0; count < c; count++ )
    rais+= rais;

    System.out.printf("the salary after raise is %f\n", rais);

    return;
}
public static void output (int[] ssNumbers, double[] salaries, double[] nSalary )
{
    System.out.printf("%10d%-20d%-20f%", ssNumbers, salaries, nSalary);
    return;
```

Comment: What does this `new int [0];` do?

Comment: Your `int[]` has a `length` of `0`, which means you cannot try to subindex it since its capacity is nil and you can't talk about any elements in it. Try switching to `ArrayList`s instead.

Comment: Sorry guys. The array size should be 10. I just edited the array size and made it 10.

Answer (score 1):

These statements:

```
int[] ssNumbers = new int [0];
double[] salaries = new double [0];
double[] nSalary = new double[0];
```

create an array of size 0. So when you try to add an element to that array, you are adding to an index that is greater than the array size. I would use an `ArrayList` so you can grow your array dynamically behind the scenes if you do not know the length.

If you have to use arrays, make sure they are big enough for the data you want to put in, eg

```
int[] ssNumbers = new int [maxSize];
```

Comment: Alright. I changed the array size to 10. Now here is the output when I try to input the social security number and the salary.

_Enter social security number12345678
Enter salary1000
Please input next security numbers or -1 to quit123456
Enter salary20000
Please input next security numbers or -1 to quit4000000
Enter salary12212
Please input next security numbers or -1 to quit_

Comment: If this solved your problem, click the green arrow next to the answer and then ask a new question, with your new problem.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `c` in the function `inputData` is exceeding the length of `ssn[]` (or maybe `sals[]`, can't tell in your code). Your boundary checking is off, try making sure that `c` is never less than `0`, or larger than the size of `ssn[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing your array to 0 in the below statement,

```
int[] ssNumbers = new int [0];
double[] salaries = new double [0];
```

And you are trying to read past 0 in the below statement (inside `inputData` function)

```
ssn[c] =  ssNum;
```

That is the error

You are reading till user inputs -1 which means that you didn't know the number of data/user-inputs prehand. Use [LinkedList](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_linkedlist.htm) instead of array.